# Only passing the first letter into the dictionary. (python 3.x)

Tags: python, dictionary

```
    print(single_website)
    print(status_str)
    print(contact_link)

    for link, status_code, contact_info in zip(single_website, status_str, contact_link):
        data = {
            "Link": link,
            "Status": status_code, 
            "Contact": contact_info
        }
```

this is how my code looks like.  It is weird that the expected value should be {link: http://wizters.com,
status: 200,
contact: Contact Info Not Available"}

However, the result is :

```
http://wizters.com
200
Contact Info Not Available
{'Status': '2', 'Link': 'h', 'Contact': 'C'}
```

Only the first letter or number is passed into the value. Btw, I used str() to make status "200" to a string.

Answer (score 1):

because strings are iterable, that is why it takes 1st later in your zip, you should wrap it into tuple or list

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> single_website = 'http://wizters.com'
>>> status_str = '200'
>>> contact_link = 'Contact Info Not Available'
>>> list(zip(single_website, status_str, contact_link))
[('h', '2', 'C'), ('t', '0', 'o'), ('t', '0', 'n')]
>>> list(zip((single_website, ), (status_str, ), (contact_link, )))
[('http://wizters.com', '200', 'Contact Info Not Available')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    management_links = [get_management_link(source, soup, single_website)]
    contact_link = [get_contact_link(source, soup, single_website)]
    status_str = [str(status)]
    single_link = [single_website]
    for link, status_code, management_info, contact_info in zip(single_link, status_str, management_links, contact_link):
        data = {
            "Link": link,
            "Status": status_code,
            "Management": management_info,
            "Contact": contact_info
        }
```

after putting these values into lists, it works now. thank you guys!